# Format for post found by tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, call

I currently have a tagging system in place with the following code

```
 rails g model tag name:string
 rails g model tagging post_id:integer tag_id:integer
 rake db:migrate

  class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :tag
  end

  class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
  end

  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
    validates_presence_of :name, :content
    attr_writer :tag_names
    after_save :assign_tags

    def tag_names
      @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
    end

    private

    def assign_tags
      if @tag_names
        self.tags = @tag_names.split(/\s+/).map do |name|
          Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  <p>
    <%= f.label :tag_names %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_names %>
  </p>
```

in the _post.html.erb partial

I am trying to call a post with a specific tag by doing

```
 <%= post.find_by_tag("sports") %>
```

When I do this all the posts with the tag come up which is what I want but they come up in this format

```
 [#<Post id: 11, title: "adfads", body: "adsfasd", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-30 06:17:52", updated_at: "2012-05-30 06:17:52", votes_count: 1>, #<Post id: 8, title: "Cover Letter", body: "Dear Human Resources:\r\n\r\nI would like to make mysel...", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-30 00:28:56", updated_at: "2012-05-30 00:28:56", votes_count: 1>]
```

How can I make them come up in a more agreeable fashion of post title post body instead of what it is rendering right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really have your find in the controller. Ignoring that issue, try this:

```
<% my_posts = post.find_by_tag("sports") %>
<% my_posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %><br />
  <%= post.body %><br />
<% end %>
```

Ideally, you would have `@posts = post.find_by_tag("sports")` in the controller, and then loop through @posts instead of my_posts. Format the above as needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how would you do it the way you suggested with @posts = post.find_by_tag("sports") in the controller because when I do I get an error that says undefined method `find_by_tag'